# Possible leak from exception?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Why would valgrind say that this is possibly leaking.

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    throw std::runtime_error("");
    return 0;
}
```

With valgrind saying (updated with full check)

```
    ==26803== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26803== Command: ./test
==26803== 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  
==26803== 
==26803== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26803==     in use at exit: 144 bytes in 1 blocks
==26803==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 176 bytes allocated
==26803== 
==26803== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==26803==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26803==    by 0x4E8FE42: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20)
==26803==    by 0x400A07: main (in /home/arynaq/HioA/DAVE3605/oppgaver/uke910/test)
==26803== 
==26803== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26803==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26803==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26803==      possibly lost: 144 bytes in 1 blocks
==26803==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26803==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26803== 
==26803== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26803== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What are these 144 bytes?

Comment: `Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory`, what does it say?

Comment: terminate calls abort; abort causes abnormal program termination;  destructors for most objects are NOT called.

Comment: @RichardCritten just tried making a dummy 100MB object before throwing, it still leaked. I thought exceptions guranteed the destructors would be called? Or is this context special in some way?

Comment: @arynaq In your example above one of the candidates for the leak is the exception object itself (it has to be copied to be thrown).  As it's not caught, terminate calls abort and abort does not clean up. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor of `std::runtime_error` allocates some memory to keep it's internals, but destructor (which supposed to free it newer called) because of stack unwinding called terminate. These valgrind mechanics just force you to catch everything in main (good practice IMHO).

```
int main() {
  try {
    /* all of your code goes here */
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::err << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  } catch(...) {
    std::err << "error: unknown exceptions" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This approach allows you also catch some exceptions to trace them other way.

Comment: A [function try block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) would be better suited here.

Comment: A technique I sometimes use is `int main() { try { return main2(); } catch(whatever...`  and have the "main" logic in `main2`

Answer (score 0):

It is also important not to use a [function try block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) as suggested above as there is a limited things that you could do inside the `catch` clause for instance call std::exit() and in such case the memory allocated by std::runtime_error will not be freed.